# Visual Studio not recognizing installed Core SDKs

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have three versions of .NET Core installed on my machine:

[image: Installed .NET Core Versions]

However, both VS2017 and VS 2019 return the following error when I execute `dotnet --version` command:

> PM> dotnet --version
>
> dotnet : Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:

I can create a solution targeting .NET Core but when I create a Console App targeting .NET Core, for example, the Debug button is labeled `Attach` instead of `Start` as usual, and `Start Debugging` and `Start Without Debugging` commands in the Debug menu are disabled.

What I tried so far:

- Added "C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet" to system PATH variable.
- Modified VS2019 using VS Installer.
- Restarted several times.

I did have several other version of .NET Core but uninstalled them since I had no solutions targeting these versions and wanted to clean up.

I only left 2.2.300 and 3.0.100 and when I used VS Installer to modify VS2019 it added SDK 2.1.700.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue without completely removing Visual Studio and installing from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently x86 version(s) of .NET Core SDKs must be installed as well. After installing 3.0.100 x86 `dotnet --version` command works fine and I can build and debug .NET Core projects...

Comment: Apparently you only got a partial answer. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/20/Adventures-in-NET-SDK-Installation-SDKs-not-Showing-Up

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link, looks like Rick investigated the whole issue thoroughly...